# Logic Apps: Parsing JSON and Filtering User Data Based on Last Sign-in Activity

Tags: json, azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps

I've defined the following logic in Logic Apps, but Parse JSON isn't capturing the signInActivity details, so I can't filter the object based on lastSignInDateTime. Basically, I'm looking for users who have an office 365 e1 license and whose lastSignInDateTime and lastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime are old (Inactive).

[image]

```
{
    "properties": {
        "value": {
            "items": {
                "properties": {
                    "accountEnabled": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "city": {
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    "companyName": {
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    "country": {
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    "department": {
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    "displayName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "employeeId": {
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    "jobTitle": {
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    "mail": {
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    "onPremisesDomainName": {
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
                        "properties": {
                            "extensionAttribute1": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "extensionAttribute10": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "extensionAttribute11": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "extensionAttribute12": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "extensionAttribute13": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "extensionAttribute14": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "extensionAttribute15": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "extensionAttribute2": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "extensionAttribute3": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "extensionAttribute4": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "extensionAttribute5": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "extensionAttribute6": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "extensionAttribute7": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "extensionAttribute8": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "extensionAttribute9": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "onPremisesSamAccountName": {
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    "onPremisesUserPrincipalName": {
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    "signInActivity": {
                        "properties": {
                            "lastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime": {
                                "type": [
                                    "String",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "lastNonInteractiveSignInRequestId": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "lastSignInDateTime": {
                                "type": [
                                    "String",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            },
                            "lastSignInRequestId": {
                                "type": [
                                    "string",
                                    "null"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "state": {
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    },
                    "userPrincipalName": {
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "accountEnabled",
                    "city",
                    "companyName",
                    "country",
                    "department",
                    "displayName",
                    "employeeId",
                    "jobTitle",
                    "onPremisesDomainName",
                    "mail",
                    "onPremisesSamAccountName",
                    "onPremisesUserPrincipalName",
                    "state",
                    "userPrincipalName",
                    "onPremisesExtensionAttributes"
                ],
                "type": "object"
            },
            "type": "array"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

Comment: Remove the filter and see if you get any results.  Then check if the results are showing the license in the filter.

Comment: Verify that the managed identity you are using has the AuditLog.Read.All permission to get the signInActivity results

Comment: @BrianSmith, I am getting the data in HTTP section but when I try to Parsing JSON its not passing this details

Comment: That's good, can you post the response example from the HTTP call? You can block out sensitive information.

Also, have you tried copying the results from the HTTP call and clicking 'use sample payload' (or something similar) on the parse json connector?

The issue I run into most with graph calls is the dynamic properties and parse json will fail if that property is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you @BrianSmith for pointing out in the right direction. After reproducing as mentioned, I could able to get the desired results.

Below is the flow of my logic app

[image]

[image]

Below is the result I got from HTTP step

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users(accountEnabled,city,companyName,country,department,displayName,employeeId,jobTitle,onPremisesDomainName,mail,onPremisesSamAccountName,onPremisesUserPrincipalName,state,userPrincipalName,onPremisesExtensionAttributes)",
  "value": [
    {
      "accountEnabled": true,
      "city": null,
      "companyName": null,
      "country": null,
      "department": null,
      "displayName": "xxx",
      "employeeId": null,
      "jobTitle": null,
      "onPremisesDomainName": null,
      "mail": null,
      "onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
      "onPremisesUserPrincipalName": null,
      "state": null,
      "userPrincipalName": "xxx",
      "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
        "extensionAttribute1": null,
        "extensionAttribute2": null,
        "extensionAttribute3": null,
        "extensionAttribute4": null,
        "extensionAttribute5": null,
        "extensionAttribute6": null,
        "extensionAttribute7": null,
        "extensionAttribute8": null,
        "extensionAttribute9": null,
        "extensionAttribute10": null,
        "extensionAttribute11": null,
        "extensionAttribute12": null,
        "extensionAttribute13": null,
        "extensionAttribute14": null,
        "extensionAttribute15": null
      }
    },
    {
      "accountEnabled": true,
      "city": null,
      "companyName": null,
      "country": null,
      "department": null,
      "displayName": "xxxx",
      "employeeId": null,
      "jobTitle": null,
      "onPremisesDomainName": null,
      "mail": "xxxx",
      "onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
      "onPremisesUserPrincipalName": null,
      "state": null,
      "userPrincipalName": "sxxx",
      "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
        "extensionAttribute1": null,
        "extensionAttribute2": null,
        "extensionAttribute3": null,
        "extensionAttribute4": null,
        "extensionAttribute5": null,
        "extensionAttribute6": null,
        "extensionAttribute7": null,
        "extensionAttribute8": null,
        "extensionAttribute9": null,
        "extensionAttribute10": null,
        "extensionAttribute11": null,
        "extensionAttribute12": null,
        "extensionAttribute13": null,
        "extensionAttribute14": null,
        "extensionAttribute15": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Parse Json schema that got generated with the above results that worked:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "@@odata.context": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
            "items": {
                "properties": {
                    "accountEnabled": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "city": {},
                    "companyName": {},
                    "country": {},
                    "department": {},
                    "displayName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "employeeId": {},
                    "jobTitle": {},
                    "mail": {},
                    "onPremisesDomainName": {},
                    "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
                        "properties": {
                            "extensionAttribute1": {},
                            "extensionAttribute10": {},
                            "extensionAttribute11": {},
                            "extensionAttribute12": {},
                            "extensionAttribute13": {},
                            "extensionAttribute14": {},
                            "extensionAttribute15": {},
                            "extensionAttribute2": {},
                            "extensionAttribute3": {},
                            "extensionAttribute4": {},
                            "extensionAttribute5": {},
                            "extensionAttribute6": {},
                            "extensionAttribute7": {},
                            "extensionAttribute8": {},
                            "extensionAttribute9": {}
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "onPremisesSamAccountName": {},
                    "onPremisesUserPrincipalName": {},
                    "state": {},
                    "userPrincipalName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "accountEnabled",
                    "city",
                    "companyName",
                    "country",
                    "department",
                    "displayName",
                    "employeeId",
                    "jobTitle",
                    "onPremisesDomainName",
                    "mail",
                    "onPremisesSamAccountName",
                    "onPremisesUserPrincipalName",
                    "state",
                    "userPrincipalName",
                    "onPremisesExtensionAttributes"
                ],
                "type": "object"
            },
            "type": "array"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: I am also getting all details but I am not able to pass the signInActivity attribute.
My Logic Apps stages are listed below.

1. Filter all E1 licensed users and select only properties that are required.

2. JSON parsing (In input signInActivity information is showing but in output signInActivity is not showing)

3. Array Filtering ( As Parsing JSON step not giving signInActivity details in Output, I am not able to filter the details further)



I'm attempting to pass the signInActivity details from the Parsing JSON steps (output) so that I can apply the filter later (next step).